# Webpack : Import CSS

Tags: javascript, webpack, fullcalendar

I have a problem with CSS. I'm using [this config](https://github.com/10up/plugin-scaffold/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js) and I want to import CSS in my script via `import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';`.

I have the following error :

```
        Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
        You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
        @charset "UTF-8";
        | .fc {
        |   direction: ltr;
        @ ./assets/js/admin/admin.js 4:0-37
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below config work for me

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then just import something like this in your js file

```
import "css/Admin/admin.css";
```